# Lightning Dialog Boxes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have a lightning component that I would like to load in a dialog box after a ui:button has been pressed. Are there any existing Lightning components for doing pop up dialogs or should I be looking at a 3rd party js library for that kind of functionality?

I don't see anything in the component reference that fits what I'm trying to do. The only thing that might fit the bill is ui:message but it seems like it's intended for simple informational messages.

Comment: there is a set of components that I am beta testing from a 3rd party vendor that will take care of this for you. Includes lookups, autocomplete, modals, tooltips, and more. It will be open source also. I can't say any more yet but it will solve this issue and make it much easier. Just know it's coming soon

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a div and hiding and showing it. It works but it would be nice to have some standard ui components to do this.

Comment: I think you're looking for a `modal` which you can find more info on here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm looking for but I was hoping to not have to roll the dialog behaviors myself. I was hoping for a lightning component, not just the slds markup.

Answer (score -2):

getUnscannedOrder:function(cmp, event, helper) {
var action = cmp.get("c.getWMSOrder");
action.setParams({ offshelfnumber : cmp.find("OffShelfid").get("v.value") });
action.setCallback(this,function(resp){
alert(JSON.stringify(resp.getReturnValue()));
cmp.set("v.flag",true);
cmp.set("v.unscannedOrder",resp.getReturnValue());
cmp.set("v.listattr",resp.getReturnValue());

```
    });
     $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
```